# rename properties for json serialization in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Haven't seen a concise answer for this, but I have a bunch of NSString properties that I would like to rename during runtime. In other languages you can do rename properties for json serialization, but not sure how to do that in objective c. I plan to use NSJSONSerialization to ultimately serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

1. Now tested.
2. Renamed all references to 'value' in my code to 'object' because in Objective-C key-value means something entirely different.

In Objective-C json is just an NSArray or NSDictionary, so you'd approach it from that point of view. Here is a sample of how you could approach it.

```
@implementation RenameJson

// Return a new array with all occurrences of a replaced by b
// Note that the array need not contain only strings but only strings are renamed
+ ( NSArray * ) renameInArray:( NSArray  * ) src
             from:( NSString * ) a
               to:( NSString * ) b
{
    NSMutableArray * dst = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:src.count];

    [src enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^ ( id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {

        if ( [obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [a isEqualToString:obj] )
        {
            [dst addObject:b];
        }
        else
        {
            [dst addObject:obj];
        }

    }];

    return dst;
}

// Return a new dictionary where all keys a are replaced by b
// Note that the keys need not all be strings but only string keys will be replaced
// No check is done for key collisions
+ ( NSDictionary * ) renameKeysInDictionary:( NSDictionary * ) src
                       from:( NSString     * ) a
                     to:( NSString     * ) b
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dst = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:src.count];

    [src enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^ ( id key, id obj, BOOL * stop ) {

        if ( [key isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [a isEqualToString:key] )
        {
            [dst setObject:obj
                forKey:b];
        }
        else
        {
            [dst setObject:obj
                forKey:key];
        }

    }];

    return dst;
}

// Return a new dictionary where all objects a are replaced by b
// Note that the objects need not all be strings but only string objects will be replaced
// No check is done for key collisions
+ ( NSDictionary * ) renameObjectsInDictionary:( NSDictionary * ) src
                      from:( NSString     * ) a
                        to:( NSString     * ) b
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dst = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:src.count];

    [src enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^ ( id key, id obj, BOOL * stop ) {

        if ( [obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [a isEqualToString:obj] )
        {
            [dst setObject:key
                forKey:b];
        }
        else
        {
            [dst setObject:obj
                forKey:key];
        }

    }];

    return dst;
}

// Given an object, array or dictionary, rename all occurrences of either
// keys or objects in a dictionary or objects in an array
+ ( NSObject * ) renameAllIn:( NSObject * ) src
            from:( NSString * ) a
              to:( NSString * ) b
{
    if ( [src isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] )
    {
        return [RenameJson renameInArray:src
                        from:a
                          to:b];
    }
    else if ( [src isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class] )
    {
        // First rename all keys
        NSDictionary * dst1 = [RenameJson renameKeysInDictionary:src
                                    from:a
                                      to:b];

        // Recursively rename objects
        NSMutableDictionary * dst2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:dst1.count];

        [dst1 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^ ( id key, id obj, BOOL * stop ) {

            NSObject * dstObj;

            if ( [obj isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] )
            {
                dstObj = [RenameJson renameInArray:obj
                                  from:a
                                to:b];
            }
            else if ( [obj isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class] )
            {
                dstObj = [RenameJson renameAllIn:obj
                                from:a
                                  to:b];
            }
            else if ( [obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [a isEqualToString:obj] )
            {
                dstObj = b;
            }
            else
            {
                dstObj = obj;
            }

            [dst2 setObject:dstObj
                 forKey:key];
        }];

        return dst2;
    }
    else
    {
        return src;
    }
}

@end
```

Test code

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSDictionary * d = @{ @"a" : @1, @"b" : @[ @1, @2, @3, @"a" ], @"c" : @{ @"a" : @"a", @"b" : @"b", @"c" : @"c" } };

        NSLog ( @"Original %@", d );

        d = [RenameJson renameAllIn:d
                       from:@"a"
                     to:@"A"];

        NSLog ( @"a -> A %@", d );

        d = [RenameJson renameAllIn:d
                       from:@"b"
                     to:@"B"];

        NSLog ( @"b -> B %@", d );

        d = [RenameJson renameAllIn:d
                       from:@"c"
                     to:@"C"];

        NSLog ( @"c -> C %@", d );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test output

```
2020-12-09 08:11:47.988151+0200 RenameJson[1041:37355] Hello, World!
2020-12-09 08:11:47.989053+0200 RenameJson[1041:37355] Original {
    a = 1;
    b =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        a
    );
    c =     {
        a = a;
        b = b;
        c = c;
    };
}
2020-12-09 08:11:47.989334+0200 RenameJson[1041:37355] a -> A {
    A = 1;
    b =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        A
    );
    c =     {
        A = A;
        b = b;
        c = c;
    };
}
2020-12-09 08:11:47.989512+0200 RenameJson[1041:37355] b -> B {
    A = 1;
    B =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        A
    );
    c =     {
        A = A;
        B = B;
        c = c;
    };
}
2020-12-09 08:11:47.989673+0200 RenameJson[1041:37355] c -> C {
    A = 1;
    B =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        A
    );
    C =     {
        A = A;
        B = B;
        C = C;
    };
}
```